# Importing Images in a Java Applet

Tags: java, image, applet, japplet

I'm trying to create an applet that loads 52 cards, shuffles them(using random number generator), then displays the top 10 cards of the deck in two rows of five. I have the HTML file with the 52 images of the cards, but is there a way to load the images without having to load each individual image. And how do you load images from the web?

Answer (score 2):

> ..is there a way to load the images without having to load each individual image

Put them in one huge image and slice it up at run-time.  There is an example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/418556).

[image]

Search Google images for 'playing+card' and it is likely there will be 2 or more tile sets in the first page of hits.

But then, even faster is to load:

1. Card backdrop
2. `Image` or **`Shape`** of each suit symbol
3. `Image` of or **`Font`** for the letters and numbers.

Then combine them at start-up to form each of the 52 cards.

It will apparently also require a common 'reverse side' for the cards.

> how do you load images from the web?

By URL.

Some alternatives:

1. [`Applet.getImage(URL)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#getImage%28java.net.URL%29)
2. [`Toolkit.getImage(URL)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getImage%28java.net.URL%29)
3. Or for a synchronously loaded `BufferedImage` use [`ImageIO.read(URL)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.net.URL%29)

The first two methods are asynchronous & require an `ImageObserver`.

Consider doing this as an application launched using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  If you proceed with using an applet, go through the [links in the applet info. page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/info).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Image[] cards = new Image[52]

private void loadImages(){
    for (int i=0; i<cards.length; i++){
        URL imgUrl = getClass().getResource("image"+(i+1));
        cards[i] = getImage(imgUrl);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: if I make all the methods in the program private, will the applet still run?

Comment: You simply call the `loadImages()` method from the `init()` method of the applet